# TextView moves when entering text in EditText

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm working on a simple HelloWorld app to get a hold of things. The app has a simple nested linear layout of a TextView that fills up most of the layout over an EditText and Send button. Whenever text is entered and "send" clicked, it adds the text to the TextView as a new line. Everything else works fine so far, but whenever the keyboard pops up to start entering text, the above TextView is pushed up as well. I would like the TextView to stay in position, and just resize in the layout.

Image 1: https://flic.kr/p/pRHo4j
Image 2: https://flic.kr/p/pRQg7i

Thanks,
pbcrazy

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/display_message"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:freezesText="true" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button_send"
                android:onClick="sendMessage" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following attribute in your Android Manifest's Activity tag

```
<activity
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem before. and funny enough i was also using LinearLayout.
Try using relative layout if you want to control the movement of things.(or make them stay put)